# Is it possible to stop a Tridion 2013 search reindex?

Tags: 2013, search

I have started a full publication reindex process using the [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-585D5C74-14E0-4E5C-A6A4-8C48B8E188CC&addHistory=true&query=search%2520host%2520reindex&scope=&tid=d467ea5f-bcf8-4f84-92f1-f5ebd3330823&filename=GUID-585D5C74-14E0-4E5C-A6A4-8C48B8E188CC.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-585D5C74-14E0-4E5C-A6A4-8C48B8E188CC&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=search%2520host%2520reindex&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1397233624573&currentQuery=search%2520host%2520reindex&currentScope=). I want to stop it...can it be done? Tried killing the Search Host, running a new reindex on a single publication, and even rebooting the machine...nothing. As soon as the search host is started back up the reindex continues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be possible. First, stop the Tridion Content Manager Search Indexer service.
Then open a 64 bit PowerShell console run as Administrator user and execute the commands as shown below:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\> Import-Module Tridion.ContentManager.Automation
PS C:\> Remove-TcmQueueMessages SearchQueue

Confirm
Are you sure you want to perform this action?
Performing the operation "Remove-TcmQueueMessages" on target "SearchQueue".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): Y
PS C:\>
```

After the queue has been purged, you can restart the Search Indexer service.

Comment: You got it :) The `Sync-TcmSearchIndex` command adds messages to the Search queue and if you remove them, the index stops. Thanks!